# How to set a different unselected style for Pivot headers?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I'm using a Pivot control with a HeaderTemplate to set the color of the header. However, I haven't found a way to change the color of the unselected pivot items. They default to an opaque version of the header color. Does anyone know how to set the color of the unselected items?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new template

[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/2146f5c9-e009-4b72-b4e9-43eec458c7cc)

Comment: What exactly in template do I need to set/update to set the color of the unselected item?